# Wrong Git URL converting (using SSH)

Tags: git, url, ssh, bamboo

We use a repository server with Git. On another server we have a CI-Software (Atlassian Bamboo) running which should pull the code via Git from our repository server. The URL structure of our repository server is offering, is the following:

```
myproject@www.blablabla.com:myproject.git
```

The CI-Server (Bamboo) tries to convert it in another Git URL structure by changing the colon at the end to a slash:

```
myproject@www.blablabla.com/myproject.git
```

Now the Link doesn't work.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a fully specified ssh remote, like this:

```
ssh://myproject@www.blablabla.com:22/myproject.git
```

If you are using gitosis on the git repository server this will work. I have not tried it with other git hosting solutions. If `myproject.git` is just a folder in the home directory of the `myproject` user you could use:

```
myproject@www.blablabla.com:/home/myproject/myproject.git
```

Comment: the solution is: ssh://myproject@www.blablabla.com/~/myproject.git :) thanks